# Action Audit on a JSF with just a Primefaces DataTable

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, primefaces, audit

I am currently auditing the user actions on a project and I am having the following Issue.
There is a functionality called *Audit Log*, which lists the complete set of Audited actions performed by the user on my system. Whenever a certain user lists the *Audit Log* this action needs to be Audited as well.
The JSF page the Audit Log is made is the following:

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="audit_List">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:breadCrumb>
                    <p:menuitem value="#{i18n['xxx']}" url="index.xhtml" />
                    <p:menuitem value="#{i18n['yyy']}"/>
                </p:breadCrumb>
                <p:panel header="#{i18n['zzz']}">
                    <p:dataTable var="auditEntry"
                                 value="#{auditList.allAuditEntries}"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 rows="10"
                                 paginatorPosition="top"
                                 dynamic="false">
                        <p:column sortBy="#{i18n[auditEntry.category]}"
                                  filterBy="#{i18n[auditEntry.category]}">
                            A column here
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column sortBy="#{auditEntryDescriptionI18N[auditEntry]}"
                                  filterBy="#{auditEntryDescriptionI18N[auditEntry]}">
                            A column here
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column sortBy="#{auditEntry.username}"
                                  filterBy="#{auditEntry.username}">
                            A column here
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="problematicColumn" 
                              sortBy="#{auditEntry.occurredOn}"
                              filterBy="#{auditEntry.occurredOn}">
                              <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="#{i18n['aaa']}"/>
                              </f:facet>
                              <h:outputText value="#{auditEntry.occurredOn}">
                                            <f:convertDateTime type="date"
                                                   ___I suspect pattern is giving the problem..___
                                                  pattern="{auditList.listDateFormat.stringValue}"
                                                  timeZone="#{sessionBean.serverTimeZone}"/>
                               </h:outputText>
                         </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I have currently the Auditing action on the particular code snippet:

```
<p:dataTable var="auditEntry"
             value="#{auditList.allAuditEntries}"
             paginator="true"
             rows="10"
             paginatorPosition="top"
             dynamic="false">
```

My backing bean:

```
public List<AuditEntry> getAllAuditEntries()
    {
        auditFacade.createAuditEntry(function that creates an audit entry);
        return allAuditEntries;
    }
```

The problem of performing the auditting on the named action of the backing bean is the following:
[image: Flooded Audit Log 1]
[image: Flooded Audit Log 2]

Need a way to have the registration of consulting the *Audit Log* just once, and not as it is being shown on the images. Any ideas? Any way to user a JSF or related tag that will guarantee the above?

TL;DR Having just a PrimeFaces DataTable on a JSF page, how to audit the opening of such page in a way to have the audit registration on a single row, not as shown on the images.
Pd: It isnt feasible to re-edit all the repetitive audit entries filtering them by time difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.
The backing bean is now `ViewScoped` and I just created a Boolean variable which ensures the Auditing is only done once per Bean `ViewScope` cycle.

```
public List<AuditEntry> getAllAuditEntries()
    {
        if (!isViewed)
        {
            isViewed = true;
            auditFacade.createAuditEntry(
                __creates Audit Entry here__);
        }

        return allAuditEntries;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is possible to put the ManagedBean in RequestScope you could call the `createAuditEntry` method in the bean`s constructor. Then it is only called once per request.

Regards.

Comment: Hi Matt.  Unfortunately the bean is already _RequestScoped_ and I tried auditing on the bean constructor. However there is a Class Instantiation exception due to updated DataTable Column on my post :(

Comment: Well I found the problem.. Since the Backing Bean is request scoped, it will instantiate a new bean each time a different page of the DataTable is selected and thus will generate a new Audit Entry... I will have to make the Backing Bean work as view scoped..

Comment: It would be interesting to know if you get rid of the exception by changing the scope.